# Windows 7 Screen Display Direction Got Change?

Tags: windows

I am using windows 7 .

position for the **screen** and **Taskbar** got change to right side of pc also the view for pc showing at right side direction.
i am dragging through mouse its not working.

i dont know which is the combination of keys e.g: ctrl+p or any other using which i can make the screen position and task bar as prior.

regards,
tousif shaikh

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below link 
http://www.ehow.com/how_8138538_change-windows-vista-horizontal-vertical.html

it work for me.

regards,
tousif shaikh.

Answer (score 0):

right click on task bar - > unselect the lock task bar - > drag it to position you want - > check the lock task bar.

Comment: no i tried this way its not working.